# C - Freeing a string too quickly and losing value?

Tags: c, string

Working on a recursive file directory explorer. As of now the code all works, but I'm going for 0 memory leaks, and my **path** string is causing issues when I free() it. As of now, I have the free() commented out because it works this way. But if I uncomment the free() the program doesn't run properly because when it starts the recursion it doesn't have a **path** value anymore to use.

Any help? Here is the code:

```
void buildTree() {
    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir;
    d = opendir(front->info);
    int root = 1;
    if (d) {
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
            char *path = (char *) malloc(2+strlen(front->info) + strlen(dir->d_name));
            if (dir->d_type == DT_DIR) {
                if (strcmp(dir->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(dir->d_name, "..") == 0)
                    continue;   
                strcpy(path, front->info);
                strcat(path, "/");
                strcat(path, dir->d_name);
                printf("%d:%d:%s\n",level,root,path);
                enq(path);
            } else {
                strcpy(path, front->info);
                strcat(path, "/");
                strcat(path, dir->d_name);
                printf("%d:%d:%s\n",level,root,path);
            }
            root++;
            //free(path);   
        }
        closedir(d);
    }
    level++;
    deq();
    if (front != NULL)
        buildTree();
}
```

Comment: `char *path = (char *) malloc(...)` You are leaking memory here. At least.

Comment: Speed has nothing to do with it. Code is sequential unless you are creating threads, and then speed would not be a problem if you synchronize correctly. Also, learn `snprintf()` instead of `strcat()` which is better in this case.

Comment: I would say your problem is undefined behavior due to mishandling a global variable. I often wonder why beginners use global variables when experts tend to avoid them, why to teach them then? Post `enq()`, I suspect you set `front->info` to `path` and then `free()` it, so you try to use a dangling pointer. Note that if you instead pass `path` as a parameter to `buildTree()` you would not have this problem.

Comment: `enq(path);` - anyone else curious what that does with that pointer, or is it just me. And just some advice: wedging recursion with global variables is nearly always a *bad* idea.

Comment: @WhozCraig There probably is another loop feeding pathames to this function. Possibly from a queue..

Comment: @wildplasser  well, if OP has recursion AND global variables AND mulitple threads dequeueing, then I suspect there may be a little problem, yes;(

Comment: You should post a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

You should add comments to your code so that it is comprehensible. There is no way to tell what you are expecting `enq(path)` to do.

When you pass information from one function to another, and the receiving function is going to put the information someplace to use it later, you have two choices.

The receiving function can make a copy of the information for itself and manage the lifetime of that copy. In that case, the calling function can use a static buffer or free its copy when it's done calling the receiving function.

Or the receiving function can take ownership of the information. In that case, the calling function must dynamically allocate the memory that will hold the information and it must not release it. It is the responsibility of the receiving function and its associated functions to free the memory when they're done with the information.

If your `enq` function follows the "take ownership" pattern, then you are right to remove the call to `free` -- you shouldn't `free` a buffer that some other code has ownership of. (Though you should call `free` in the `else` path because there `enq` doesn't take ownership.) You should ensure that some other code somewhere does free that buffer at some later point where it's no longer needed.